# comparing two directories with separate diff output per file

Tags: diff

I'd need to see what has been changed between two directories which contain different version of a software sourcecode. While I have found a way to get a unique .diff file, how can I obtain a different file for each changed file in the two directories? I'd need this, as the "main" is about 6 MB and wanted some more handy thing.

Answer (score 1):

I came around this problem too, so I ended up with some lines of a shell script. It takes three arguments: Source and destination directory (as used for diff) and a target folder (should exist) for the output.

It's a bit hacky, but maybe it would be useful for someone. So use with care, especially if your paths have special characters.

```
#!/bin/sh

DIFFARGS="-wb"

LANG=C
TARGET=$3
SRC=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/\//\\\\\\//g'`
DST=`echo $2 | sed -e 's/\//\\\\\\//g'`

if [ ! -d "$TARGET" ]; then
  echo "'$TARGET' is not a directory." >&2
  exit 1
fi

diff -rqN $DIFFARGS "$1" "$2" | sed "s/Files $SRC\/\(.*\?\) and $DST\/\(.*\?\) differ/\1/" | \
while read file
do
  if [ ! -d "$TARGET/`dirname \"$file\"`" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$TARGET/`dirname \"$file\"`"
  fi
  diff $DIFFARGS -N "$1/$file" "$2/$file" > "$TARGET"/"$file.diff"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare source code it is better to commit it to a source vesioning program as "svn".

after you have done so. do a diff of your uploaded code and pipe it to file.diff

```
  svn diff --old svn:url1 --new svn:url2 > file.diff
```

Comment: I did it with git as I hadn't SVN installed. The problem is that I wanted a way to get one .diff for each different file, and not a global .diff. I'll work on the whole file, anyway, since there isn't a solution, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

A bash for loop will work for you. The following will diff two directories with C source code and produce a separate diff for each file.

```
for FILE in $(find <FIRST_DIR> -name '*.[ch]'); do DIFF=<DIFF_DIR>/$(echo $FILE | grep -o '[-_a-zA-Z0-9.]*$').diff; diff -u $FILE <SECOND_DIR>/$FILE > $DIFF; done
```

Use the correct patch level for the lines starting with +++